# Adding Variable to Script for sms

Tags: php

I use a class to implement the sms etc but its not triggring at 100% due to variables i cant seem to get from other php pages.
I need to add more variables at the if statement so that the sms messages can be unique to their status and type etc that the user inputs,
so the basic code is below i would appreciate some help.

```
    $acc_id = $upd->getField('account_id');
   $status = $upd->getField('status');
    $meetingtype = $upd->getField('');
    error_log($status);
  //show me how to add account name? accounts.name
  $acc_id = $upd->getField('account_id');
  $acc = new Account();
  $acc->retrieve($acc_id);
  $acc->primary_phone;
  error_log($acc->name);
  $sms = new DawproSms();
  $sms->number = $acc->primary_phone;
  $themeetingtype = $upd->getField('');
  $theStatus = $upd->getField('status');

  if ($theStatus == 'Held')
  {

   $sms->message = "Your Moovah removal is confirmed for <date><time>@ <location>. Should you have any questions, kindly contact SA Taxi on 0861 88 99 88.";
   $sms->number = '0123456789';
   $return = $sms->send();
   if ($return){
    error_log('SMS Sent!');
   } else {
    error_log('There was a problem sending the SMS');
   }
  }
else  if ($theStatus == 'Held')
  {
   $sms->message = "Your SA Taxi Media removal is confirmed for <date><time>@ <location>. Should you have any questions, kindly contact SA Taxi on 0861 88 99 88.";
   $sms->number = '0123456789';    
$return = $sms->send();
   if ($return){
    error_log('SMS Sent!');
   } else {
    error_log('There was a problem sending the SMS');
   }
  }
else  if ($theStatus == 'Held')
  {
   $sms->message = "Your SA Taxi Media and Moovah removal is confirmed for <date><time>@ <location>. Should you have any questions, kindly contact SA Taxi on 0861 88 99 88.";
   $sms->number = '0123456789';    
$return = $sms->send();
   if ($return){
    error_log('SMS Sent!');
   } else {
    error_log('There was a problem sending the SMS');
   }
  }
else  if ($theStatus == 'Accepted')
  {
   $sms->message = "Your Moovah branding replacement is confirmed for <date><time>@ <location>. Questions? Contact SA Taxi on 0861 88 99 88.";
   $sms->number = '0123456789';    
$return = $sms->send();
   if ($return){
    error_log('SMS Sent!');
   } else {
    error_log('There was a problem sending the SMS');
   }
  }
```

Comment: so, what's your trouble here? i didn't see any question here

Comment: Your question  is a tad confusing because your two If sentences as the bottom with "$theStatus" is practically the same.

Comment: I am Trying to get it to trigger on a status and another variable for example a specific product field value in another module/page -  Developing on a SugarCRM system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand out from your question, you want multiple conditions in your IF sentence? If that's the case you can do it like this:

```
if($theStatus == 'Held' && $status== 'Mover'){
 //code
}
```

If however you only want to validate on one field/Variable you can also do it like this:

```
switch($theStatus){
   case "Held":
      //sms code thing 
      break;
   case "Accepted":
      //Sms code thing
      break
}
```

You can see a more detailed description of switch here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php